# Parse pass image data to cloud function from iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Now I save an object from the client app with an image. This is the code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_photoImageView.image);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];

PFObject *newItem = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Item"];

[newItem setObject:imageFile forKey:@"photo"];
[newItem saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        //...

    } else {

        //...  
    }
}];
```

I'm transferring it inside a function in the Cloud code to simplify the code across platforms. How I transfer the image to the function?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        //...
                        THIS, @"photo",
                        nil];

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"saveNewItem"
               withParameters:@{@"data": dictionary}
                        block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                            if (!error) {

                            } else {

                                NSLog(@"Error");

                            }
                        }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass URL of your photo's `PFFile`, and then use this url in Cloud Code to process data. 
So your data dictionary could look like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    //...
                    imageFile.url, @"photoURL",
                    nil];
```

Comment: I want to avoid the use of pffile. Now I'm trying with base64 encoding